# got error " The "RazorGenerate" task failed unexpectedly. " .After Updating to VS 16.8 and upgrade to .net 5.. the core version target is Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core

[image]

When Build Project. Error The "RazorGenerate" task failed unexpectedly. .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Can you share the project file of the project that's having an issue?

Comment: No sorry because it is confidential

Comment: You can try to add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All"/>` in your project file.

Comment: bug fix...i remove all file and clone again

Comment: Glad you can solve it

Comment: Note: I started getting this problem with two ASP.NET Core webapps targeting net472, only AFTER I updated VS to 16.8 (16.8.1 in this case). The @RobPowell answer solved it.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28333

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The fix for me was to introduce a new System Environment Variable with the Key "DOTNET_HOST_PATH"  and the value "dotnet" and then to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: It solved for me. I wonder why the update no longer added this variable !?

Comment: It even attempts to tell you in the exception:
Error MSB4018 The "RazorTagHelper" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: **DOTNET_HOST_PATH is not set**
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.blah...

Comment: Actually this worked if you set the Environment Variable in the OS, not the project.

Comment: @mgPePe, I was using system environment variables, I'll edit my answer to clarify, thanks.

Comment: I believe project Environment Variables are only for the program as it is running, not for the system doing the compiling.

Comment: Why did this happen? I installed .NET 5 just two days back so my scenario matches up well with this question.

Comment: just VS restart after adding this variable was enough for me

Comment: I know this worked for a lot of people, but it didn't work for me. Adding the environment variable and restarting VS, did nothing :(

Comment: @Nick where are you adding the environment variable?

Answer (score 47):

I did 3 steps to get it to build AND to get the ( ~/ ) variable to work.

1. Open cmd and write this: setx DOTNET_HOST_PATH "%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
2. Open C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk in here delete the folder: NuGetFallbackFolder
3. Restart your pc!

Comment: Just deleting the NuGetFallbackFolder worked for me after updating to VS 2019 Pro 16.8.1, didn't restart PC but restarted VS. Thank you!

Comment: I had to follow all 3 steps to get mine to work after updating to VS 2019 16.8.1. Additionally, had to had references manually via NuGet for Newtonsoft.Json. Did not have to restart PC.

Comment: See the following from Microsoft. It's basically the same thing...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1224054/aspnet-core-22-framework-project-fails-to-build.html

Comment: The first and third step solved the problem on my system. 

I don't have any folder with NugetFallBackFolder in that path.

Answer (score 36):

It worked on the build server, after I added this Nuget package:

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor

Since I added the Net.SDK.Razor package, it builds successfully.

I had also added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design, but only Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor is actually needed.

Comment: Actually, adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design is what resolved it for me.

Comment: Adding Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor solves the problem. Not solved by simply adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design for me